Derivate involving Bessel function of second type
Let.
$$f := (x, y) \mapsto \text{BesselK}(1, c \cdot (a - b \cdot (x + y))) \cdot \exp(c \cdot b \cdot (y - x))$$
Is there a close formula for this $$\frac{\partial^{m+n}}{\partial y^m \partial x^n} f(0,0)$$.
Thank you in advance.
